# JQuery: onchange event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Trying to show/hide a text file based on the users selection in a select. I believe my problem is with the if statement.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#drpStatus").change(function(){
    if( $(this).val() == 'Married'){
      $("#txtSpouse").show();
    else
      $("#txtSpouse").hide();
  });
});
</script>

</head>

<body>
<input type="text" id="txtSpouse" style="display:none">
<select name="drpStatus" id="drpStatus">
            <option value="Single" selected="selected">Single</option>
            <option value="Dating">Dating</option>
            <option value="Married">Married</option>
          </select>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Look at the console: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token else`. Please learn how to debug JavaScript: http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple syntax error, you have an extra `{` after your `if`. Remove it and this works.

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/yNqfM/

js

```
$("#drpStatus").change(function(){
 if( $(this).val() == 'Married') /*removed the {*/
  $("#txtSpouse").show();
 else
  $("#txtSpouse").hide();
});
```

Comment: or even better add a closing one for the if and a pair for the else

Comment: @RuneFS - You could always add more. But when considering js, sometimes less is more. This fix works.

Comment: it works but is considered bad practice and will be flagged by tools such as jslint

Comment: @RuneFS - Many libraries use this approach for simple if else statements. Go post some of your flags on jquery's forum if you feel so strong about it. Having less script means the script loads faster. Speed > nitpick.

Answer (score 0):

You made a syntax error. you added a { after your if statement but you never end it. you can either remove it, or you can change it to } else { /** code **/ }

Answer (score 0):

Try below code :
Link for jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kbSrR/

```
 $(function(){
    $("#drpStatus").change(function () {
        if ($(":selected",$(this)).text() == 'Married') 
            $("#txtSpouse").show();
            else $("#txtSpouse").hide();
        });
    });
```